# Dynamic multidimensional array in .txt file

Tags: c, arrays, multidimensional-array

I'm beginner in C and I'm trying to perform operations dynamically allocated to and read from a file input.txt. The problem is that I can not find the error that is causing the "segmentation fault". Will allocate the matrices and perform operations increasingly finding '+' or '-' signs. When you find '=' sign, I will print the result in a file output.txt.

My initial code is allocating the array like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

double ***AlocarMatriz(int p, int m, int n)
{
    int i, j;
    double ***Matriz;
    Matriz = (double***) malloc (p * sizeof(double**)); // alloc number of plans
    for (i = 0; i < p; i++){
        Matriz[i] = (double**) malloc (m * sizeof(double*));
        if (Matriz[i]==NULL)
            printf("plain"); // alloc rows
        for (j = 0; j < p; j++){
            Matriz[i][j] = (double*) malloc (n * sizeof(double));
            if (Matriz[i][j]==NULL)
                printf("plain"); // alloc cols
        }
    }
    return Matriz;
}

void ImprimeMatriz(double ***Matriz, int p, int m, int n)
{ // print matrices
    int i, j, k;
    for(i = 0; i < p; i++){
        for(j = 0; j < m; j++){
            printf("\n");
            for(k = 0; k < n; k++){
                printf("%.2lf ", Matriz[i][j][k]);
            }
        }
    }
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    double*** A;
    int x, y, z;
    scanf("%d", &x);
    scanf("%d", &y);
    scanf("%d", &z);
    A = AlocarMatriz(x, y, z);
    //double A[x][y][z];

    ImprimeMatriz(A, x, y, z);

    system("PAUSE");


    return 0;
}
```

I tried to create a code to read the file and get the arrays that will be like this:

```
       2    //instances - number of operations
       2 2 2 //dimension of matrix - plan, row and column
       0 1   // first matrix
       1 0
       0 1
       1 0
       +   //operation
       0 1 //second matrix
       1 0
       0 1
       1 0
       =   //flag for stop and print result in output.txt file
```

My code for open txt file:

```
       FILE *fent;

//int m, n, p, i, j, k;


if (argc != 3) {                      
    fprintf(stderr, "Entry with correct params numbers!!!\n");
        exit(1);
}

fent = fopen (argv[1], "r");         //try open file
if (fent == NULL) {                  
    fprintf("Error to open %s for entry \n", argv[1]);
    return -1;
    }




fclose(fent);

return (EXIT_SUCCESS);
```

I'm not able to continue because I don't understand where I am going wrong.
Tks for your help.

Comment: Your *second* for-loop in your allocator is wrong. This: `for (j=0; j < p; j++)` should be this: `for (j = 0; j < m; j++)`

Comment: Thanks WhozCraig. I'll make the changes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for (j = 0; j < p; j++){
            Matriz[i][j] = (double*) malloc (n * sizeof(double));
```

should be :

```
 for (j = 0; j < m; j++){
            Matriz[i][j] = (double*) malloc (n * sizeof(double));
```

And hope you can initialize you memory before you use it.

Comment: Thanks folks. I'll make the changes.